# How to save optionbutton session in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, session, activexobject, radio-button

The optionbutton1 and 5 child/s will only show if enabled. How can I retain or save the last clicked of parent-child relationship if I jump 1st parent to 2nd parent. This is should be equivalent to session/cookies, I dunno in vba.

1. Click OB1, enabled sub-OB2,3,4
2. Click sub-OB3
3. Click OB5, enabled sub-OB6, 7 and DISABLED sub-OB 2, 3,4
4. Click sub-OB7
5. Click OB1, <*GO TO LAST CLICKED sub-OB*>

   Optionbutton1

   - Optionbutton2
   - Optionbutton3
   - Optionbutton4

   Optionbutton5

   - Optionbutton6
   - Optionbutton7

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have marked the question with tag activexobject  and ActiveX objects do indeed have a property bag persistence mechanism.  An Excel worksheet does serve as a possible site for hosting ActiveX controls and thus should persist the properties of ActiveX controls.

*Have you actually tried changing the state of the option buttons, saving the workbook, then reopening?  It might work already.*

EDIT: In fact just tested it, it works for me.